# MVC4 .NET ListBoxFor Selected property ignored

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, listbox

I made a ListBox for Tags, which are bound to a note. The Create View works fine, however I'd like to have the already selected Tags preselected in the ListBox in the Edit View. 
While running the code below, the ListBox appears, however none of the Tags is selected. I tried to debug it and noticed, that the controller correctly assign the selected property. Also while checking the "Model.Tags" in the View, it shows them correctly until it executed that line in the View - then all the selected properties are backto "false"

The view is a strongly typed view of :

```
public class TagViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Tags { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> SelectedTags { get; set; }
}
```

The controller

```
 using (var db = new NoteContext())
        {
            Note note = db.Notes.Find(id);
            TagViewModel tagViewModel = new TagViewModel();
            List<SelectListItem> tags = new List<SelectListItem>();

            foreach (Tag tag in db.Tags)
            {
                bool isSelected = false;

                if ( note.Tags.Exists(tagElement => tagElement.TagId == tag.TagId)) 
                {
                    isSelected = true;
                }

                SelectListItem selectListItem = new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Text = tag.Name,
                    Value = tag.TagId.ToString(),
                    Selected = isSelected
                };

                tags.Add(selectListItem);
            }

            tagViewModel.Tags = tags;

            return View(tagViewModel);
        }
```

and the HTML helper in the View

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedTags, Model.Tags)
```

(Sorry for my broken English)

Comment: There is no point setting the `Selected` property of `SelectListItem` - its ignored when you bind to a model property. Its the value of the property which determines what is selected. You need to set the value of `tagViewModel.SelectedTags = ....` before you pass the model to the view.

Comment: Everything seems to be good. I just created a sample fiddle with the ViewModels you use. Please find the fiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/SOI1ox

On load, selected items will be pre-selected in the List box.
On submit, the "SelectedTags" will contain the list of selected items

Comment: @Developer, And I have [forked it here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rUYbKi) to show you that setting the `Selected` property is pointless

Comment: @StephenMuecke - Gotcha. thats true, ideally SelectedTags property is to be set on load...But OP din't set SelectedTags in his initial load (like in my fiddle), so the "pre-selection" should work for him, just wondering what went wrong.

Comment: That's kind of shameful ^^'  So logical after rereading the code. I don't know why, I had in my head that tagViewModel.SelectedTags was only an output for afterwards. Thx a lot!